# WPF treeview to be used as menu (MVVM style)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, treeview

I have a requirement in which a menu should be implemented as a treeview on the left side of a window.

I know how to populate the treeview with the (menu)data (the mvvm way).

But: how do i hook up each object in the treeview to an ICommand (in the Viewmodel)?? so that e.g. double clicking an object results in opening a window??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Rather than figure out how to make a treeview behave like a menu, why not use a menu, and use custom templating to present it in a treeview-like way?  In WPF it's generally easier to use the control with the desired behaviour and change its appearance than to use the control with the desired appearance and change its behaviour.

Comment: +1 itowlson.
If you want a menu that look like a tree view, use a menu and style it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem should be solved in another way but...

- You would have the command on your
  view model as a property.
- You derive    from treeview and
  treeview item.
- You    give the treeview item a
  command    property, you bind this to
  your view    model's command in the
  tree views    itemContainerStyle (in
  the xaml)
- You    override the preview mouse
  down on    the tree view item to call
  the    command

here is a sample TreeViewItem

```
   public class EditableTreeViewItem : TreeViewItem {

      public ICommand DoubleClickCommand {
         get { return (ICommand)GetValue(DoubleClickCommandProperty); }
         set { SetValue(DoubleClickCommandProperty, value); }
      }

      // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DoubleClickCommand.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
      public static readonly DependencyProperty DoubleClickCommandProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("DoubleClickCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(EditableTreeView), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));



      protected override void OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {

         if (this.DoubleClickCommand!= null) {
            this.DoubleClickCommand.Execute(this.DataContext);
            e.Handled = true;
         }
         base.OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick(e);
      }

      protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride() {
         return new EditableTreeViewItem();
      }

      protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item) {
         return item is EditableTreeViewItem;
      }
}
```

and a treeview to use this item

```
 public class EditableTreeView : TreeView {

      //generate the tree view item
      protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride() {
         EditableTreeViewItem item = new EditableTreeViewItem();
         return item;
      }

      protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item) {
         return item is EditableTreeViewItem;
      }
}
```

now as some smart people have said above, you would be better off using a menu and styling it. now when you double click the treeview item it will call the command instead of expanding/collapsing as it should.

this is how you would use it in the xaml

```
         <controls:EditableTreeViewMode=OneWayToSource}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItemsSource}">
             <controls:EditableTreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <!-- This Style binds a TreeViewItem to a the ViewModel. -->
                <Style
                   TargetType="{x:Type controls:EditableTreeViewItem}">
                   <Setter
                      Property="DoubleClickCommand"
                      Value="{Binding OpenNewWindowCommand}" />
                </Style>
             </controls:EditableTreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
          </controls:EditableTreeView>
```

Comment: ...to be honest: never thought about doing it this way!! though i have used similar approach in other fields! Sounds very interesting and 'll give it a try. Thanks very much for opening a blinds man eyes!